# Bind domains to application pages

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, routes

Lets check the scenario:

I have a `tbl_Users` and mapped http://mydomain/[username] to each user's profile using routes.  They have some routed pages in their profiles (like contacts, etc).

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
     "UserProfiles",
     "{username}",
     "~/views/ShowProfile.aspx"
     );

 routes.MapPageRoute(
    "UserProfilesContacts",
    "{username}/contactus",
    "~/views/ShowContact.aspx"
 );
```

Now I need to let them register domains for themselves and map their domains to their profile pages (I don't want to forward domain! I want to see their own URL).

```
http://aDomain.com  == search in db ==>  http://mydomain.com/[aUser]
```

And so

```
http://aDomain.com/contactus ==search in db==>  http://mydomain.com/[aUser]/contactus
```

I kept their domain lists in the database. I know that I have to add their domains to IIS (or domain alias to mydomain.com)

I want to let them work in their domain like their profile in main domain.

What's the solution in ASP.NET 4?